# Download image using requests that contains a query string

Tags: python, image, url, python-requests, instagram

I am trying to download an image from an instagram media URL:
https://instagram.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/p1080x1080/106602453_613520712600632_6255422472318530180_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=WQizf6rhDmQAX883HrQ&oh=140f221889178fd03bf654cf18a9d9a2&oe=5F4D2AFE

Pasting this into my browser will bring up the image, but when I run the following code I get the following error which i suspect is due to issues with the URL containing a query string (running this on a simple url ending in .jpg works without issue

```
  File "C:/Users/19053/InstagramImageDownloader/downloadImage.py", line 18, in <module>
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '106602453_613520712600632_6255422472318530180_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=WQizf6rhDmQAX883HrQ&oh=140f221889178fd03bf654cf18a9d9a2&oe=5F4D2AFE'
```

Full code as follows:

```
## Importing Necessary Modules
import requests  # to get image from the web
import shutil  # to save it locally

## Set up the image URL and filename
image_url = "https://instagram.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/p1080x1080/106602453_613520712600632_6255422472318530180_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=WQizf6rhDmQAX883HrQ&oh=140f221889178fd03bf654cf18a9d9a2&oe=5F4D2AFE"
filename = image_url.split("/")[-1]

# Open the url image, set stream to True, this will return the stream content.
r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)

# Check if the image was retrieved successfully
if r.status_code == 200:
    # Set decode_content value to True, otherwise the downloaded image file's size will be zero.
    r.raw.decode_content = True

    # Open a local file with wb ( write binary ) permission.
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

    print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ', filename)
else:
    print('Image Couldn\'t be retreived')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the filename. You need to first split by `?` then take the first element then split by `/`

```
import requests  # to get image from the web
import shutil  # to save it locally

## Set up the image URL and filename
image_url = "https://instagram.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/p1080x1080/106602453_613520712600632_6255422472318530180_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=WQizf6rhDmQAX883HrQ&oh=140f221889178fd03bf654cf18a9d9a2&oe=5F4D2AFE"
filename = image_url.split("?")[0].split("/")[-1]

# Open the url image, set stream to True, this will return the stream content.
r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)

# Check if the image was retrieved successfully
if r.status_code == 200:
    # Set decode_content value to True, otherwise the downloaded image file's size will be zero.
    r.raw.decode_content = True

    # Open a local file with wb ( write binary ) permission.
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

    print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ', filename)
else:
    print('Image Couldn\'t be retreived')
```